# How to implement recursive inclusion relationship in a struct?

Tags: elixir

Define a simple structure that will contain its own type structure data:

```
defmodule MyNode do
  defstruct [:parent, :child]
end
```

Create parent and child nodes:

```
iex> p = %MyNode{}
%MyNode{child: nil, parent: nil}
iex> c = %MyNode{parent: p}
%MyNode{child: nil, parent: %MyNode{child: nil, parent: nil}}
```

Assign child nodes in the parent node:

```
iex> p = %{ p | child: c } 
%MyNode{
  child: %MyNode{child: nil, parent: %MyNode{child: nil, parent: nil}},
  parent: nil
}
```

Yes, we are stuck in an infinite loop. We can never get a reasonable structure data that contains each other.

I understand the reasons for all this. But I still have this need, how should I design the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With all the terms being immutable, as in [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir), this is impossible.

> I still have this need

This is unlikely; the design might be altered to make this not necessary: after all, the existing solutions for everything overcome this in different ways, and having two objects cross-referencing each other is superfluous. If you were sharing more details of your particular problem, we could suggest better alternatives.

What you can do, you can either run a process (e. g. [`Agent`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Agent.html?)) backing up each `MyNode` and update internal states. Or, alternatively, you might keep the whole list/graph in the `Agent` *and* provide accessors for `get_parent/1`/`get_child/1` through this process, looking up the respective node(s).